# Formal word for "wow factor"

Tags: formality

I am wondering if there is any formal word or phrase for "wow factor" that shows same level of excitement positively.

Comment: The OED has copious entries on *wow*, since 1920 - but nothing, so far, on *wow factor*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**stupendousness** - so large or great that it amazes you. ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stupendous))

Answer (score 1):

***[Peculiarity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peculiarities)***:

> - A notable or distinctive feature or characteristic.

(AHD)

[Wow factor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wow-factor)(informal):

> - A quality or feature that is extremely impressive:
>
>   - *its funky, futuristic looks would add a definite wow factor to any kitchen*

(ODO)

Answer (score 1):

**Specialty**

[Webster's Definition of Specialty:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/speciality)a special or distinguishing feature or characteristic

wow factor:     a quality or feature that is extremely impressive.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be :

**Charm** : *the power or quality of delighting, attracting, or fascinating others.*

> This feature has a wow factor that is irresistible

becomes

> This feature has a charm that is irresistible

Answer (score 0):

Astounding : causing amazement and wonder

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/astounding